# Is a torsion-free discrete abelian group of finite rank isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^k_d$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a torsion-free discrete abelian group of rank $k$, then is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to a group $H$, where $\mathbb{Z}^k < H < \mathbb{Q}^k_d$?

Here, $\mathbb{Q}^k_d$ is the product $\mathbb{Q}^k$ with discrete topology and 
"$<$" stands for subgroup.

Comment: Do you mean Prufer rank? Then see the reference given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_k\}$ be a maximal linearly independent subset of $G$ and let $H=\langle g_1,g_2,\dots,g_k\rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by those elements. The quotient $G/H$ is torsion, because of maximality, so from the exact sequence
$$
0\to H\to G\to G/H\to 0
$$
we get, tensoring by $\mathbb{Q}$, that $H\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $G\otimes\mathbb{Q}$. In particular $G\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Q}^k$, because $H\cong\mathbb{Z}^k$. The map $G\to G\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ defined by $x\mapsto x\otimes 1$ is injective.

Now compose this map with an isomorphism $G\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}^k$. If the image of $G$ under this monomorphism does not contain $\mathbb{Z}^k$ it's easy to compose with the multiplication by a suitable integer and get the result you want.